# DynamicModule - Bookmarks / Autorun menu?

Tags: dynamic

Using DynamicModule in my code, I observed that there is no Bookmarks / Autorun menu (the small "+" in the upper right corner...). Is it possible to add it somehow and to make Bookmarks available only for a few, selected variables?

Comment: You might be able to simulate that behavior using the `SaveDefinitions` and `UnsavedVariables` options of `DynamicModule`. However, wouldn't it be easier to use `Manipulate` and strip out what you don't need, instead of trying to re-build it in `DynamicModule`?

Comment: @MarcoB: I think you're right, I'll try to re-write the code using Manipulate, thanks.